# Undefined array key when submit a form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to submit a simple form which anable the admin to add an artist in database.
I've got an 'Undefined array key' at ligne 50.

Is it possible to help me please ?

Here is the Artistcontroller :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Artist;
use App\Repository\ArtistRepository;
use App\Form\ArtistType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Service\Utils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;

class ArtistController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/artist', name: 'app_artist')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('artist/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ArtistController',
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/admin/artist/all', name:'app_admin_artist_all')]
    public function showAllArtist(ArtistRepository $artistRepository):Response{
        //récuperer dans un tableau tous les articles
        $artists = $artistRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render('artist/index.html.twig', [
            'list'=> $artists,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/admin/artist/create', name: 'app_admin_artist_create')]
    public function artistCreate(EntityManagerInterface $em, ArtistRepository $repo,
    Request $request, SluggerInterface $slugger):Response
    {   
        $msg = "";
        //Instancier un objet contact
        $artist = new Artist();
        //instancier un objet formulaire
        $form = $this->createForm(ArtistType::class, $artist);
        //récupérer les données
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        //test si le formulaire est submit
        if($form->isSubmitted()){
            //nettoyage des inputs
            $name = Utils::cleanInputStatic($request->request->all('artist')['name']);
            $style = Utils::cleanInputStatic($request->request->all('artist')['style']);
            $resume = Utils::cleanInputStatic($request->request->all('artist')['resume']);
            //set des attributs nettoyé
            $artist->setName($name);
            $artist->setStyle($style);
            $artist->setResume($resume);
            
            $file = $form->get('file')->getData();
            // this condition is needed because the 'brochure' field is not required
            // so the PDF file must be processed only when a file is uploaded
            if ($file) {
                $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
                $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
                $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$file->guessExtension();

                // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
                try {
                    $file->move(
                        $this->getParameter('artist_uploads'),
                        $newFilename
                    );
                } catch (FileException $e) {
                    // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
                }

                // updates the 'brochureFilename' property to store the PDF file name
                // instead of its contents
                $artist->setProfilePicture($newFilename);
            }
            
            //persister les données
            $em->persist($artist);
            //ajoute en BDD
            $em->flush();
            $msg = "L'artiste : ".$artist->getName()." a été ajouté en BDD";

        }
        return $this->render('artist/form.html.twig', [
            'msg'=> $msg,
            'form'=> $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

}
```

Here is the ArtistType:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Artist;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

class ArtistType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form'],
                'label' => 'Nom : ',
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('style', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form'],
                'label' => 'Styles : ',
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('resume', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form'],
                'label' => 'Présentation : ',
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('profilePicture', FileType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'submitForm'],
                'label' => 'Ajouter une photo de profil',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '20M',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/png',
                            'image/jpeg',
                            'image/jpg',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Merci de joindre un fichier .png ou .jpeg',
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('Envoyer', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Artist::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried to use an other form i've done for the project and it doesn't work when i use it for this Entity

Comment: welcome to SO, try to share form.html.twig and the artist entity.

Answer (score 0):

Your key error at line 50 seems to be about those lines:

```
$name = Utils::cleanInputStatic($request->request->all('artist')['name']);
$style = Utils::cleanInputStatic($request->request->all('artist')['style']);
$resume = Utils::cleanInputStatic($request->request->all('artist')['resume']);
```

Are you sure about how you are accessing artist data ? Try dumping $request and checking wheter your keys are correct or not.

You could also just use your form instead of the request:

```
$name = Utils::cleanInputStatic($form->getData()->getName());
$style = Utils::cleanInputStatic($form->getData()->getStyle());
$resume = Utils::cleanInputStatic($form->getData()->getResume());
```

Since you did not post your entity, I'm not sure how to get your name, style & resume. But you get the gist of it.